# call mv in nested expression in tcsh won't work

Tags: encoding, nested, csh, tcsh, codepages

I have some dirname with '?????' characters, can't determine codeset, using convmv, So I tried to do following

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d > list
edit list with cutting others that ./????... 
mv `cat list` new_dir
```

But it won't work, may I ask why, and how to rename this dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ouput of `cat list` gets embedded inside the `mv` command line, and it confuses the shell.

To fix, the output should be encapsulated inside double quotes, which is achieved like this:

```
mv "`cat list`" new_dir
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `-exec` to `find`, there's no need for the intermediate `list` file:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec mv {} new-name \;
```

This should pass the arguments correctly, even those with spaces or other characters that require escaping.

Note that this will only work if you "find" a single file.

Comment: question about why this doesn't work - preoritized. I can't separete exact dir name from others in case wrong encoding.